# How to correctly derive Encryption Key from user's password?

Tags: php, security, encryption

I'm using `hash_pbkdf2()` algorithm to derive the Encryption Key from the user's password, i'm doing like this:

```
$salt = random_bytes(16);
$interactions = 250000;
$size = 256;
$encryptionKey = hash_pbkdf2(
    "sha384",
    $password,
    $salt,
    $interactions,
    $size,
    0
);
```

My problem is that I do not know what to do with `$salt`, since it is randomly generated the first time, but it should be the same at other times as the user logs in to the system to derive the same encryption key and, in this way, the encrypted data can always be decrypted without problems.

What i must to do with the salt? Store it (crypted maybe) or is it not secure?

Comment: Store the salt appended to the password hash. Ensure that the salt stays at a fixed length so that you can retrieve it as a substring. The salt is only to slow down brute force attempts and prevent rainbow table usage.

Comment: I got  it :) Thanks!